# utf-8 pytest output converted to ascii with \x

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, pytest

If I write a simple test (which will be failing) to check UTF-8 strings (see example below) and launch it using py.test, the output with errors will be ascii-encoded with `\x`.

**test:**

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def test():
    assert "тест" == "тест1"
```

**output:**

```
def test():
>       assert "тест" == "тест1"
E       assert '\xd1\x82\xd0...1\x81\xd1\x82' == '\xd1\x82\xd0\...\x81\xd1\x821'
E         - тест
E         + тест1
E         ?         +

test.py:3: AssertionError
```

The question is: is there a way to make a output normal (with py.test)? I mean without `\x`, like a `E       assert 'тест' == 'тест1'`.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like you should file a bug.  By the look of the output there's a bug in assertion rewriting and in python's difflib.

Comment: any news? solutions? cannot google this :)

Comment: @spacediver I created a [bug](https://bitbucket.org/pytest-dev/pytest/issue/319/utf-8-output-in-assertion-error-converted) for pytest and it was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it was a bug and it fixed: https://bitbucket.org/pytest-dev/pytest/issue/319/utf-8-output-in-assertion-error-converted.